# Este código me va en Windows 10 pero no en WindowsXP

Tags: vb.net, vba

He conseguido hacerme una aplicación de consola para que me imprima el pdf que le pase por parámetro. En w10 me funciona pero al llevármelo a un XP me abre el programa pero no el archivo y no se me imprime.

Lo quiero para meterlo en un métodos de Access97 para que me imprima un pdf. 
También sería interesante si alguien me lo tradujera para que el vba de accesss97 me lo entienda.

gracias.

```
    Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
        Try
            Using p As New Process
                p.StartInfo.FileName = args(0).ToString
                p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print"
                p.Start()

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) ' tiempo X para que el programa cliente se active he imprima

                p.CloseMainWindow() ' Cierre ventana cliente
                ' si la ventana sigue abierta, se encicla hasta cerrarla.
                While Not p.HasExited
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                    p.CloseMainWindow()
                End While
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Tienes instalado algun lector de pdfs en el sistema con Windows XP?

Comment: Si, Creo que el problema es que por defecto aunque tengo configurado el Reader 9 el programa usa el Reader profesional 6. No se como arreglar eso.

Comment: Prueba a dar con el boton derecho del ratón en un archivo pdf, abrir con... y seleccionas el reader 9 marcando el check de "utilizar siempre el programa seleccionado..."